# Python: Lowpass Filter with only numpy

Tags: python, numpy, fft, lowpass-filter

I need to implement a lowpass filter in Python, but the only module I can use is numpy (not scipy). I tried using `np.fft.fft()` on the signal, then setting all frequencies which are higher than the cutoff frequency to 0 and then using `np.fft.ifft()`.
Howerver this didn't work and I'm not shure how to apply the filter at all.

**EDIT:**
after changing `np.abs()` to `np.real()` the result was almost correct.
But in the spectrogram the amplitudes are smaller then in the original and the filterd refernce (difference of 6dB). So it looks like it's not completely right. Any Ideas what could be done to fix that?

my Lowpass Function should take the following arguments:

```
signal: audio signal to be filtered
cutoff_freq: cout off frequency in Hz above which to cut off frequencies
sampling_rate: sampling rate in samples/second
```

The filterd signal should be returned.

my current function

```py
    def low_pass_filter(adata: np.ndarray, bandlimit: int = 1000, sampling_rate: int = 44100) -> np.ndarray:
        # translate bandlimit from Hz to dataindex according to sampling rate and data size
        bandlimit_index = int(bandlimit * adata.size / sampling_rate)
    
        fsig = np.fft.fft(adata)
        
        for i in range(bandlimit_index + 1, len(fsig)):
            fsig[i] = 0
            
        adata_filtered = np.fft.ifft(fsig)
    
        return np.real(adata_filtered)
```

Comment: I guess you'll have to specify the requirements on the lowpass in order for people to come up with reasonable suggestions.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "_this didn't work_" - how exactly?

Comment: So I added details on what's  the specific Problem. And I added my current code. Unfortunately I can't Upload the audio file I have to filter, because it's not my own.

Comment: Indeed, if the IFFT returns complex values (with an imaginary component significantly different from 0), then there is something wrong in your filter. In your case, it is not preserving the conjugate symmetry in the frequency domain. If you do that right, your IFFT will return a complex array, but with an approximately zero imaginary component. Take the real part of that (not the magnitude).

Comment: You don't need to upload a file. You should plot the steps and explain, first to yourself, where the process breaks down.

Comment: @CrisLuengo. If course it's doing that if you don't set the zeros symmetrically, and respect the extra zero.

Comment: @Cris Luengo. Thank you. I changed abs() to real() and now the result looks much better. But what would I need to do to ' preserve[...] the conjugate symmetry'? I often read something like that, but I don't know what that means/ how to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see that the comments of @Cris Luengo have already developed your solution into the right direction. The last thing you're missing now is that the spectrum you obtain from `np.fft.fft` is composed of the positive frequency components in the first half and the 'mirrored' negative frequency components in the second half.

If you now set all components beyond your `bandlimit_index` to zero, you're erradicating these negative frequency components. That explains the drop in signal amplitude of 6dB, you're eliminating half the signal power (+ as you already noticed every real signal has to have conjugate symmetric frequency spectrum). The `np.fft.ifft` function documentation ([ifft documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.ifft.html)) explains the expected format quite nicely. It states:

"The input should be ordered in the same way as is returned by fft, i.e.,"

- a[0] should contain the zero frequency term,
- a[1:n//2] should contain the positive-frequency terms,
- a[n//2 + 1:] should contain the negative-frequency terms, in increasing order starting from the most negative frequency.

That's essentially the symmetry you have to preserve. So in order to preserve these components just set the components between `bandlimit_index + 1 -> (len(fsig) - bandlimit_index)` to zero.

```
    def low_pass_filter(adata: np.ndarray, bandlimit: int = 1000, sampling_rate: int = 44100) -> np.ndarray:
        # translate bandlimit from Hz to dataindex according to sampling rate and data size
        bandlimit_index = int(bandlimit * adata.size / sampling_rate)
    
        fsig = np.fft.fft(adata)
        
        for i in range(bandlimit_index + 1, len(fsig) - bandlimit_index ):
            fsig[i] = 0
            
        adata_filtered = np.fft.ifft(fsig)
    
        return np.real(adata_filtered)
```

or maybe if you want to be slightly more 'pythonic', you can also set the components to zero like this:

```
fsig[bandlimit_index+1 : -bandlimit_index] = 0
```

Here's a colab to walk through:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RR_9EYlApDMg4jAS2HuJIpSqwg5RLzGW?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you very much, your explanation was really helpfull. now my result also fits the reference and the colab walk through really helped my understaning :)

Answer (score 5):

A full FFT of a real signal contains two symmetrical halves. Each half will contain reflected (purely imaginary) complex conjugates of the other half: everything past Nyquist is not real information. If you set everything to zero past some frequency, you have to respect the symmetry.

Here is a contrived signal, sampled at 1kHz, and its FFT:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 10000, endpoint=False)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 2 * t) * np.exp(-0.5 * ((t - 5) / 1.5)**2)
f = np.fft.fftfreq(t.size, 0.001)
F = np.fft.fft(y)

plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(t, y)
plt.title('Time Domain')
plt.xlabel('time (s)')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(np.fft.fftshift(f), np.fft.fftshift(F.imag), label='imag')
plt.xlim([-3, 3])
plt.title('Frequency Domain')
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Imginatry Component')
```

[image]

The frequency axis looks like this:

```
>>> f
array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2, ..., -0.3, -0.2, -0.1])
```

Notice that aside from the DC component (bin 0), the axis is symmtrical about the midpoint, with the highest (Nyquist) frequency in the middle. This is why I called [`fftshift`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftshift.html) to draw the plot: it rearranges the array to go from smallest to largest.

You don't need to restrict your inputs to integers most likely. A fractional `band_limit` is totally acceptable. Keep in mind that to convert frequency to index, you multiply by size and sampling frequency (divide by ram, rather than divide:

```
def low_pass_filter(data, band_limit, sampling_rate):
    cutoff_index = int(band_limit * data.size / sampling_rate)
    F = np.fft.fft(data)
    F[cutoff_index + 1 : -cutoff_index] = 0
    return np.fft.ifft(F).real
```

You still need to return the real component, because the FFT will always have some imaginary roundoff errors in the lowest couple of bits.

Here is a plot of the sample signal cut off above 2Hz:

```
y2 = low_pass_filter(y, 2, 1000)
f2 = np.fft.fftfreq(t.size, 0.001)
F2 = np.fft.fft(y2)

plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(t, y2)
plt.title('Time Domain')
plt.xlabel('time (s)')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(np.fft.fftshift(f2), np.fft.fftshift(F2.imag), label='imag')
plt.xlim([-3, 3])
plt.title('Frequency Domain')
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Imginatry Component')
```

[image]

Remember how we said that only half of the FFT of a purely real (or purely complex) signal contains non-redundant information? Numpy respects this, and provides [`np.fft.rfft`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html), [`np.fft.irfft`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.irfft.html), [`np.fft.rfftfreq`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfftfreq.html) to work with real-values signals. You can use this to write a simpler version of the filter, since there is no longer a symmetry constraint.

```
def low_pass_filter(data, band_limit, sampling_rate):
     cutoff_index = int(band_limit * data.size / sampling_rate)
     F = np.fft.rfft(data)
     F[cutoff_index + 1:] = 0
     return np.fft.irfft(F, n=data.size).real
```

The only caveat is that we must explicitly pass in `n` to `irfft`, otherwise the output size will always be even, regardless of input size.

Comment: helpfull! was unaware of the nifty `np.fft.rfft` :-)